# Make a requests funnel in Parallel.ForEach statement

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, plinq

What I have:

- Remote API that allow to make one request in the second
- Need to request this API on behalf of different users (with different tokens) in same time

I have a some kind of this code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(accounts, currentAccount =>
{
    GetDataFromApiForAccount(currentAccount);
})
```

Parallel will run GetDataFromApiForAccount methods for x amount of accounts in same time, but api allow to perform one request from one api in one second.

So I need to have some code, that will make some kind of funnel for requests flow - one request in one secconds.

Is it possible? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Put each request in a queue to be processed, and read that queue once every second.

Comment: MSMQ will not return to me the value of API calls.

Comment: So use a callback, that handles the returned value. And I didn't mean specifically MSMQ. There are several messaging queue libraries and technologies, or even the Queue-class.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a readymade solution, but it's a pretty wide problem. =)

Comment: Yep, even it's a pretty wide problem, i did not find the solution in google :) the problem is that inside GetDataFromApiForAccount i have a foreach loop that get data page-by-page from Api. So it should be some abstraction under current Repository that gets data from Api.

Comment: PLINQ is for data parallelism, ie you already have your data and want to process it. What you are asking here is Task parallelism which should be handled using either simple Tasks or a dataflow library like TPL dataflow.